# How can we retrieve the values ​​of the intervals in the legend in R

Tags: r, legend

I have an elevation model plotted in R
Code:

```
library(raster)
data(volcano)
r <- raster(volcano)
plot(r, col = topo.colors(20))
```

Plot:
[image]

how can we retrieve the values ​​of the intervals in the legend, that is, in the example-->100,120,140,160,180

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you hope to do with the intervals? +1 for a reproducible example.

Comment: I want to made ​​for my application ploter the upper variable, above 180 and below 100 that's just an example I want to get an idea across.

Comment: Are you interested in defining the intervals yourself, or do you need to stay with the default intervals?  Is this what you are looking to do?: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17352/8104

Comment: I am looking to define them! how I can get the values ​​of the interval? in the example we have given color for each known interval through the pads. but I want to automatically extract values​​. I do not know if I'm clear or I give more precision?

Comment: oupss ,"I meant in my last comment, I'm not looking to define them" I want to extract them,sorry!

Comment: look at [Legend properties when legend.only=T (raster package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436947/legend-properties-when-legend-only-t-raster-package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legend is a summary of the raster values.  Therefore, you will need to extract the pertinent raster values.  This should do it:

```
library(raster)
data(volcano)
r = raster(volcano)

min = minValue(r)
max = maxValue(r)
l = c(min:max)
result = l[l %% 20 == 0]

> result
[1] 100 120 140 160 180
```

Comment: Hello @Aaron That was what I needed!! Thank's a lot for your help :)